# Problems when using a client to obtain server certificate in Python 3.6

Tags: python, ubuntu, openssl, centos

I am trying to obtain the server certificate using the client. Below is just the relevant part of my code written in Python 3.6:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((mailhost, int(port)))
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = True
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
s = ctx.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=mailhost)
cert_bin = s.getpeercert(True)
```

After running this code I obtain the following error when calling the "wrap_socket" method:

```
[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:847)
```

The client has OpenSSL 1.1.0g 2 Nov 2017 and is running Ubuntu 18.04, and the server has OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips 26 Jan 2017 and is running CentOS 7.6.

Is this problem related to the different versions of OpenSSL?

Comment: It most likely seems to be due to different SSL versions being exchanged between Server and Client. Try doing a packet capture to see what Hello Messages are exchanged to zero-in on the problem.

Comment: Can you post the "Client Hello" packet contents here? Most likely Server is not accepting the TLS version being proposed by client.

Comment: I made a packet capture using Wireshark and at the moment when the TLS session should establish, only the "Client Hello" packet is transmitted from the client to the server. The "Server Hello" packet is not transmitted. I searched on the Internet and I found some examples using getpeercert() Python method. These examples imply the use of an HTTP server. Also, in the Python documentation is written that this method can be used for SMTP and POP3 servers. I don't understand if this operation (obtaining the server certificate) requires a web server software to be installed at the server side.

Comment: I posted the SSL related contents of the packet:
https://pastebin.com/hZR07tT7 .
If it's necessary to post more information about the packet, please tell me.

Comment: "Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)" - The version being sent by Client is TLS 1.2. Are you sure your server supports it?

Comment: Can you post your server side code? Where are you running the SSL Server?

Comment: The server is a mail server. Dovecot and Postfix services are installed on this server. Yes, these services are configured to support TLS 1.2. I also have a script through which the client sends and receives emails to/from the server using SMTP and POP3 over which the SSL layer has been applied using STARTTLS (the established session is using TLS 1.2). I can send and receive emails successfully using this script. The problem is that the code posted in my question is used only to get the server certificate. I think that the error in this code is not related to the TLS session itself.

Comment: If I can send and receive emails, this probably means that the problem is not generated by the different OpenSSL versions of the client and server. I think that the problem is related to the incorrect use of the defined socket. I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think that I need to create a service on the server that listens to the client's request.